# How to use helper classes in zf2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2 for web apps. 
In a controller Action I would create some PDF Documents. I'd like to use a helper class for developing the methods creating the PDF. 
What is the best place to store the class? inside the controller directory? Or does the framework provide some better place in its architecture for doing this? Or even better methods or concepts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a directory called Plugin under the Controller directory. A good name for your plugin will have the 'Plugin' termination.

If your plugin will only have one method you can put your logic in the __invoke method:

```
public function __invoke($data)
{
    // [ process $data ]
}
```

If not and you need more methods, then your invoke method will have to return your plugin instance:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    return $this;
}

public function otherMethod($data)
{
    // [ process $data ]
}
```

Then you have to register your plugin in the module.config.php creating a new key called 'controller_plugins':

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'myPdf' => 'MyModule\Controller\Plugin\MyPdfPlugin',
    ),
),
```

You can use there the same methods that are used for every kind of service in the module.config.php: invokables, factories, abstract_factories, aliases, ...

And now you are ready to use it in your controller:

```
$this->myPdf($data);
```

In the case you have more than one methods:

```
$this->myPdf()->otherMethod($data);
```